# Tricky norm-inequality $\|x\|_p \le n^{\frac{1}{p}- \frac{1}{r}} \|x\|_r.$ for $p \in (0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

For $r>p \ge 1$ one can show that in $\mathbb{C}^n$ we have

$$\|x\|_p \le n^{\frac{1}{p}- \frac{1}{r}} \|x\|_r.$$ My question is now: Does this also hold for $1 \ge r>p>0$? Obviously we cannot use Holder's inequality directly, but maybe a nifty trick could do it?

Comment: Have you tried to check this inequality on the "usual suspects" (simple test vectors)? (As far as I could tell from back-of-the-envelope such attempts, it does hold for simple examples, so at least it's not ruled out.)

Comment: yes, I also checked several examples and could not find a counterexample.

Comment: Very similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837497/variant-of-holders-inequality-x-p-le-n-frac1p-frac1r-x-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $a_1, \dots , a_n \ge 0.$ Because the function $x\to x^{r/p}$ is convex on $[0,\infty),$ Jensen implies

$$\left (\frac{a_1^p+ \cdots + a_n^p}{n}\right )^{r/p}\le \frac{1}{n}\left(a_1^p)^{r/p}+ \cdots + (a_n^p)^{r/p}\right).$$

The inequality follows from this quite handily.