# Variant of Holder's inequality: $\|x\|_p \le n^{\frac1p- \frac1r} \|x\|_r$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, normed-spaces

So far I believed that only the reverse Holder inequality holds for $0<p<r<1,$ but then a student pointed out to me that 
$$\|x\|_p \le n^{\frac{1}{p}- \frac{1}{r}} \|x\|_r.$$ A few numerical examples suggest that this holds. And for $r,p>1$ this is just Holder, but where does this inequality come from then?

Comment: Are the $\|\cdot\|_p$ the $\ell_p$ norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @WillieWong yes, indeed.

Comment: Very similar question (which was shown in the sidebar among related questions): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837282/tricky-norm-inequality-x-p-le-n-frac1p-frac1r-x-r-for

Answer (score 1):

The standard [Holder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) (for points in $\mathbb{R}^n$) can be written as

$$ \|fg\|_p \leq \|f\|_q \|g\|_r $$

where $p^{-1} = q^{-1} + r^{-1}$; note that this requires $q, r \geq p$.

The inequality you wrote above follows by taking $r^{-1} = p^{-1} - q^{-1}$ and $g = \mathbf{1}$.

---

The version above can be proved by taking $\tilde{f} = |f|^p$ and $\tilde{g} = |g|^p$ and applying the standard version quoted in Wikipedia.

---

In arbitrary measure spaces, what you have is the estimate

$$ \|x\|_p \leq |\mathrm{supp}(x)|^{\frac1p -\frac1q} \|x\|_q $$

for every $q \geq p$, provided the support of the function $x$ has finite measure. This is sometimes useful in probability theory.